# Trying to understand parent fingerprint in HD wallets

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, c#, deterministic-wallets

I'm trying to implement a barebones HD wallet generator in C#.  I'm starting with a mnemonic and derivation path `m/0'` and want to generate BIP141 p2wpkh-in-p2sh addresses.  Obviously for the Master Node the fingerprint is `0x00000000`, but when I get to depth 1 (`0'`), I need to calculate the fingerprint of the parent key.  My question is, is the formula `RipeMD160(parentPrivKey)` or `RipeMD160(SHA256(parentPrivKey))`?  I've been looking at Ian Coleman's implementation in javascript (https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) and he seems to do the latter one.  However, on [this site](https://blog.aeternity.com/implementing-extended-keys-in-%C3%A6ternitys-elixir-wallet-e70303dec433) under "Parent Fingerprint", it says it's the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `ripemd160(sha256(parentpriv))` also known as `hash160(parentpriv)` [source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#key-identifiers). There is also a python implementation [here](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools/blob/master/btctools/HD/bip32.py)

Comment: Wrong. It's `ripemd160(sha256(compressed parent pub))[0:4]`. Your link also says it clearly: *Hash160 (RIPEMD160 after SHA256) of the serialized ECDSA **public key***

Answer (score 1):

Can't use comments because of reputation, but both the question and the answer is saying that the fingerprint is based on private key. It should be the hash160 of the PUBLIC key. for even if you are deriving a private key you should use the parents PUBLIC key for generating the fingerprint. This is important to make both a derived public and a derived private key having  the same fingerprint so you can relate them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

A number of HD wallet fingerprint test vectors for curves secp256k1, nist256p1, and ed25519 are provided at the bottom of https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md#test-vector-1-for-ed25519. Notice all top tier fingerprints are 00000000.

For https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md#test-vector-1-for-secp256k1 **Chain m/0H**, the fingerprint is computed from its parent's public key as follows:

**% echo 0339a36013301597daef41fbe593a02cc513d0b55527ec2df1050e2e8ff49c85c2 | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | cut -c 1-8**

`3442193e`

**% echo 0339a36013301597daef41fbe593a02cc513d0b55527ec2df1050e2e8ff49c85c2 | bx bitcoin160 | cut -c 1-8**

`3442193e`